# Java Scanner class nested calls for input not working on subsequent calls

Tags: java, arrays, input, cucumber, java.util.scanner

How could I read input from the console using the Scanner class? Something like this:

System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
Scanner = input(); // Or something like this, I don't know the code
Basically, all I want is have the scanner read an input for the username, and assign the input to a String variable.

Comment: Please don't describe your code, show it instead, in the form of a [example].

Answer (score 1):

Your first scanner object has flushed all data from your stream. So while the first instance can provide tokens to you the next one would deal with an empty stream.

I would revisit the design of your game. First of all I would set the stream as a dependency for your game so that you could "hardcode" stream for your test or use System.in for your production case.

Scanner has also be one for your entire game so that you won't recreate it each time you get input.